# How to resolve the host name of yodobashi.com?

Tags: javascript, networking, browser

It's possible to open the page of yodobashi.com in my browsers, both chrome and firefox, but its hostname can't be resolved by my code on GAS(Google Apps Script) and my code gets timeout when trying to send an http request. In addition to it, I confirmed that the hostname can't be resolved by nslookup, ping, and curl. Is there any tricks to resolve yodobashi.com. 
(By the way, yodobashi.com is a very famous online shopping site hosted by Yodobashi Camera, which is one of the largest electronic retail shop.)